# Как получить список запущенных приложений на Android?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно получить список запущенных процессов и их «состояние» (кэширован или основной в текущий момент и т.п.).

Может через `PackageManager` и `ApplicationInfo` можно получить статус Только вот как? Куда копать?

Answer (score 4):

Нашел ответ.

```
// Get running processes
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
if (runningProcesses != null && runningProcesses.size() > 0) {
    // Set data to the list adapter
    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, runningProcesses));
} else {
    // In case there are no processes running (not a chance :))
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No application is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```